# Importing nodejs project in to eclipse IDE

Tags: java, android, eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

I am new to eclipse, i have a nodejs project in my local system. 
Also I want to import that nodejs project structure to eclipse also i want to make that mobile apk file.

```
Say for example simple app folder structure might be:
-css
-pages
-js
-index.html
```

Java knowledge should be there for apk development? if not how can i import my nodejs front end project into IDE and make that to mobile app?

Comment: NodeJS can't import to android project. That's difference project structure and NodeJS is JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import as Node.js project use Nodeclipse CLI

```
nodeclipse -p
```

then import as existing project

read http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/

To make Android app, I would start from new Android app,
then adding Node code into `assests` folder